# Convert a dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this data like this

```
technologies = [
            ("a","2","3"),
            ("4","5","6"),
            ("7","8","9")
            ]
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies,columns = ['C1','C2','C3'])
print(df)
```

and i convert it to this df

```
  C1 C2 C3
0  a  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

then i convert DataFrame to Dictionary of Records

```
df2 = df.to_dict('records')
print(df2)
```

and i got this

```
[{'C1': 'a', 'C2': '2', 'C3': '3'}, {'C1': '4', 'C2': '5', 'C3': '6'}, {'C1': '7', 'C2': '8', 'C3': '9'}]
```

Now i want my output would be like this

```
[{'C1': 'a',
  'C2': '2', 
  'C3': '3'}, 
 {'C1': '4', 
  'C2': '5', 
  'C3': '6'}, 
 {'C1': '7', 
  'C2': '8', 
  'C3': '9'}]
```

Is there anychance to get my expect output? i'm just the beginner, please help me to find out

Comment: in my eyes,  got one and desired one look same

Comment: I guess OP is talking about the formatting and not the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pprint.pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) for that. Something like this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> d = [{'C1': 'a', 'C2': '2', 'C3': '3'}, {'C1': '4', 'C2': '5', 'C3': '6'}, {'C1': '7', 'C2': '8', 'C3': '9'}]
>>> pprint(d, width=10)
[{'C1': 'a',
  'C2': '2',
  'C3': '3'},
 {'C1': '4',
  'C2': '5',
  'C3': '6'},
 {'C1': '7',
  'C2': '8',
  'C3': '9'}]
>>>
```

And with the default `width`, the output is the following:

```py
>>> pprint(d)
[{'C1': 'a', 'C2': '2', 'C3': '3'},
 {'C1': '4', 'C2': '5', 'C3': '6'},
 {'C1': '7', 'C2': '8', 'C3': '9'}]
>>>
```